# getting values from stdClass Object

Tags: php

I try to get values of stdClass Object into php variables. And i looked for other solutions but i couldn't success. Here is my result.

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [messages] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [apiMessageId] => db55468cdb274551b9e18c973ec780f4
                    [accepted] => 1
                    [to] => 1111111
                    [error] => 
                )

        )    
    [error] => 
)
```

I want to get only "apiMessageId" section but as i said i couldn't get this. I tried "$object->messages[0]->apiMessageId;" but no results on the screen. Anyone to help me please?

and this is my php code for request.

```
        function Conn($url){
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
        $cikti = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return str_replace(array("\n","\t","\r"), null, $cikti);
    }

$url1 = "https://platform.clickatell.com/messages/http/send?apiKey=xxx&to=xxx&content=Test+message+text";
$Conn = Conn($url1);
$res = json_decode($Conn);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Try using `var_dump($object->messages[0]->apiMessageId)` and let us know what you get...

Comment: thanks for your answer. I tried what you said and i get "NULL" on the screen.

Comment: Wow... In that case, either that variable doesn't have access to the ... there seems to be some issue with the access.

Comment: Are you really accessing the same object as you've dumped?

Comment: So do you have any idea for i have to do about this issue? Because i can get array with "print_r" function.

Comment: Could you show us your code for trying to access the object and your `print_r()` (and any code in between)? A simple copy/paste.

Comment: Of course you can find pastebin link and see my code https://pastebin.com/NUqqkHae

Comment: Please update your question instead of linking off site. Questions needs to be complete to be helpful for future visitors. Also, show us where you're trying to access the property. Btw, why are you running `str_replace()` on the response? Don't you get a proper json-string?

Comment: this is the json string what you asked. {"messages":[{"apiMessageId":"ba8eca9079e04c24843c64eeb4bebce2","accepted":true,"to":"xxx","error":null}],"error":null}

Comment: Thanks, but that wasn't really what I asked for. You should add your code, the request, where you dump the response and where you try to access the property _to your question_. Do _not_ add it off site and link to it. (And it was still missing how and where you're trying to access the property).

Comment: i gave the link before pastebin.com/NUqqkHae you can see my total code on this pastebin.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. This is the query what i need.

```
echo $res->messages[0]->apiMessageId;
```

I wrote before

```
echo $object->messages[0]->apiMessageId;
```

but my variable name is not object. The variable name is $res.